# How can I show that $\frac{i}{2}Log(z+i) - \frac{i}{2}Log(z-i)$ is an antiderivative of $\frac{1}{1+z^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Show that$$\frac{i}{2}\log(z+i) - \frac{i}{2}\log(z-i)$$ is an antiderivative of $$\frac{1}{1+z^2}$$

This is for $\Re(z) > 0$.

I think I would need to rewrite this somehow and apply the Cauchy Riemann equations, but I'm sure there is a better way.  Right now I'm working ahead in my book to get a head start.

Comment: What happens if you derive?

Comment: Simply differentiate the logarithmic expression...

Answer (score 1):

- $$\frac{1}{1+z^2}=\frac{1}{(z+i)(z-i)}=\frac{i}{2(z+i)}-\frac{i}{2(z-i)}$$

So using your method:

$$\int\frac{1}{1+z^2}\space\text{d}z=\frac{i}{2}\int\frac{1}{z+i}\space\text{d}z-\frac{i}{2}\int\frac{1}{z-i}\space\text{d}z=$$
$$\frac{i}{2}\int\frac{1}{u}\space\text{d}u-\frac{i}{2}\int\frac{1}{s}\space\text{d}s=\frac{i\ln\left|z+i\right|}{2}-\frac{i\ln\left|z-i\right|}{2}+\text{C}$$

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite $$\frac{1}{1+z^2}=\frac{1}{(z+i)(z-i)}$$ Now, using partial fraction decomposition,
$$\frac{1}{(z+i)(z-i)}=\frac{1}{2 i (z-i)}-\frac{1}{2 i (z+i)}=\frac{i}{2  (z+i)}-\frac{i}{2  (z-i)}$$ Now, integrate to get the result.

Comment: You've made a mistake in the last part, it has to be $\frac{i}{2(z\color{red}{-}i)}$

Comment: @JanEerland. Thanks for pointing it ! Cheers